# Multiple implementations of EventHandler in AEM

Tags: java, osgi, aem

I am writing code to catch replication event in AEM, for this I am implementing the interface `org.osgi.service.event.EventHandler`.

I have two implementaions of this interface `HandlerOne` and `HandlerTwo`, what I have observed is when I deploy the application in AEM, `handleEvent()` method in either `HandlerOne` or `HandlerTwo` is called and not both, and from what I observe it calls the service that registered last.

Is there a way to make it work with both implementations?

I am working on AEM 5.6.1 and below is the code snippet.

```
@Component
@Service
@Property(name = "event.topics", value = "com/day/cq/replication")
public class HandlerOne implements EventHandler {
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        log.debug("In handler one");
    }
}

@Component
@Service
@Property(name = "event.topics", value = "com/day/cq/replication")
public class HandlerTwo implements EventHandler {
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        log.debug("In handler Two");
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would expect all handlers to be called. How exactly do you register the EventHanders?

Comment: Is the event.topic same for both Listeners? You can add snippet for both Listeners

Comment: @SandeepKumar I have updated my question with the code snippet.

Comment: As per [documentation](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/tutorials-how-tos/how-to-manage-events-in-sling.html) _As this service is an event handler, we have set the immediate flag to true on the component._. Can you try adding `(immediate=true)` in `@Component`

Comment: Let us know if it worked

Comment: I actually merged the code in both classes into one singel class.